# Xcode 5 running with iOS7 look and feel with Base SDK 6.1

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

So, I've been updating this app that has a BaseSDK of 6.1.

So far it has been fine, until this afternoon. I ran it once on my iPhone 5 and it was fine (but crashed). It was running with the iOS6 look and feel like I wanted.

Fixed the bug (just a simple index out of bounds bug) and ran it again and now it runs with the iOS7 look and feel.

I've checked the deployment target and the Base SDK and I have no idea why it's doing this.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

**SOLVED**

OK, so I managed to fix it.

I had to...

Quit Xcode.
Delete Derived Data.
Delete the app from my phone.
Restart my Mac and Xcode.
Rerun "pod update" for my cocoapods. (I tried this before with no luck).
Then start it all up again.

Now it's fine.

I haven't changed any code and all the Base SDKs and deployment targets are the same.

Oh well...???

Comment: Is your code in SCM? Can you diff the project/code to determine what else has changed?

Comment: The look and feel depends on the OS version you're running it on, not the SDK you're building against.

Comment: Could you post the code that you changed?

Comment: It was literally adding an if statement to a function that gets something from an NSArray.

Comment: I got same issue when i try to run app build for base sdk 6.1 and deployment target 6.1, it was giving iOS 7 look and feel on simulator. But when I test it on device it works fine and Look and Feel was of 6.1
And also when i run app from xCode 4 on simulator with iOS 7 it was working fine. I only got issue when I run app with xCode 5 on simulator.

Answer (score 0):

Xcode 5 does not support SDK 6.1.

You can trick it to use it, but the behaviour is undefined.

Comment: This undefined behaviour is possibly what I was experiencing.

Comment: where you get this? and it's no trick to add an older sdk to xcode5 it's the same as with older xcode and skd versions

Comment: Why is the behaviour undefined? Wouldn't it act as if an iOS 7.0 device was running an app that wasn't yet compiled with 7.0 as the base SDK?

Comment: Take a look into the apple developer forums. Apple states Xcode 5 is only guaranteed to work with SDK 7. The old technique of copying an older SDK into Xcode is officially declined.

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple SDKs installed, then Xcode 5 has a bug (or undefined behaviour, whatever) where it shows the connected devices twice (or N times for N SDKs installed) in the drop down where you select simulator/device. 
Each of these icons will access the connected device using one of the SDKs you have installed, so even though they look the same, they'll have some odd side effects.
I always use the top one.. (better ideas welcome)